# Can install certificate in cert store, but not in IIS binding list

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate

Having an issue, I have a pfx file cert that a client provided.   I can import this certificate in Certificate Manager and it does have a private key, but I cannot use the certificate in bindings for IIS.  The private key is not re-exportable.   It doesn't show up in the drop downs.   When I try and import this certificate in IIS Server Certificates, I get the error message.

Certificate cannot be used as an SSL server certificate.

One note, the CSR never originated from the IIS server.   I just asked to purchase a cert, and the client made one and sent over the PFX file.

Not sure if there is a workaround or I need to have the client re-key the certificate based on my CSR.   I tried looking at this other answer, but didn't seem to help.   Probably because the private key is not exportable?   Not sure, please advise.

[Installed SSL certificate in certificate store, but it's not in IIS certificate list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009834/installed-ssl-certificate-in-certificate-store-but-its-not-in-iis-certificate)

Comment: That answer was incomplete, so you probably installed the certificate to a wrong account. In MMC you must choose the computer account and then install the certificate to its Personal store.

Comment: Double clicked on the cert, picked the computer account then installed the certificate to its Personal store as you described.    I see the cert in Personal\Certificates in MMC.    However in IIS, when I try and create a site binding for port 443, the certificate is not listed in the SSL certificate dropdown to select.

Comment: Then I can only say you applied/installed a wrong certificate. IIS Manager only shows a valid "server" certificate who has the mandatory purpose of "Server Authentication", https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2012/02/17/client-certificates-vs-server-certificates/

Comment: Thanks, any way I can explain or give instructions to the client other than it needs to be a server certificate?    In MMC, it shows Client Authentication.   Do I need to create a CSR from IIS and have them process it to be a server certificate?

Comment: The certificate you got is a client certificate then. To apply a server certificate, any valid CRS can be used (not necessary from the IIS machine). Please ask your client to follow the instructions of the CA he/she uses.