# IIS can't see certificate

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate

I created this certificate:

openssl req -x509 -out localhost.crt -keyout localhost.key 
-newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 
-subj '/CN=localhost' -extensions EXT -config <(printf "[dn]\nCN=localhost\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")

and have tried installing it in both the Personal and 'Trusted Root Certificate Authorities' but when I try and bind to it in IIS for https it doesn't show up in the 'SSL certificates:' drop down. The certs 'Intended Purposes' is 'Server Authentication'.

Comment: If you only install that .crt file in IIS Manager, then it won't work https://blog.lextudio.com/the-whole-story-of-server-certificate-disappears-in-iis-7-7-5-8-8-5-10-0-after-installing-it-why-b66e802baa38

Comment: There is the same problem here, you can use it as a reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009834/installed-ssl-certificate-in-certificate-store-but-its-not-in-iis-certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009834/installed-ssl-certificate-in-certificate-store-but-its-not-in-iis-certificate).