# Private key missing while importing certificate from internal CA

Tags: ssl, iis, private-key, ca

certificate expired in `IIS` My task to renew it

I created CSR using `mmc` and using `IIS /create certificate request` for my internal CA
They released to me `.cer` file. but while I import it to `mmc/Certificates/Personal/Certificates` there is missing privite key.

And because of missing privite key my `IIS` server not accepting it. While I import cert dissapeares.

I tried to fix using `certuitil -repairstore my xxx` looking for some Smart Card not helped.

I even tried to create using `openssl` same issue no private key.

I already made crazy my CA with my unlimited CSR.

Where I'm doing wrong? Why there is missing private key even I do all operation on the same server
**Issue from my side or CA?**

[image]

Comment: Instead of just importing the certificate you also need to link the private key.  I don't know if MMC exposes an option to complete a request if you look in the "Requests" store, or if you have to use `certreq -accept`, or if there's yet a different graphical way these days.

Comment: @bartonjs I did as u suggest, giving below error `Expected -user | -machine argument
Certificate Request Processor: Cannot find object or property. 0x80092004 (-2146885628 CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND)`

Comment: This error(0x80092004 ) indicates that certreq was unable to find related request object in the Certificate Enrollment Requests node in the certificate store. About private key you can refer to: https://www.entrust.com/knowledgebase/ssl/what-are-the-steps-to-recover-the-private-key-of-an-ssl-certificate-in-an-iis-environment#:~:text=A%20missing%20private%20key%20could,Wizard%20rather%20than%20through%20IIS. When certificate was installed correctly but no private key, refer to the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21009835/20058276.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny, My CA incorreclty issued certificate.
There was missing 3rd level, They was sending me chain cert, not actual cert.

I compared below

[image]